# Masking(PatternMask) with MudBlazor not working in Blazor hybrid

Tags: mudblazor, maui-blazor, blazor-hybrid

I am trying to use the MudBlazor library to mask a phone number,card number input in a **Blazor hybrid app**, but it is not working as expected. Here is the code that I am using:

```
<MudTextField Mask="@(new PatternMask("00 00 00 00 00"))" Label="phone Number"
                      @bind-Value="phoneNumber" Variant="@Variant.Text" Clearable />
```

This code works well in a Blazor webassembly project, but when i try to use it in a **Blazor hybrid app**, the masking feature does not work.
Has anyone else encountered this issue with .net maui blazor or blazor hybrid? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note:**I tried the example provided in the link below, but it doesn't seem to be working for blazor hybrid:
https://mudblazor.com/features/masking#multimask